# Javascript Regex: Match any non-word character that is not a whitespace character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using https://regexr.com/ to test a regular expression. I'm trying to validate a name input on a form, so:

- Only letter characters
- No non-letter characters except backspace and space

In my validation function, I can have:

```
    if (/\d/.test(charStr)) {
            return false;
        }
```

`/\d/` will match numbers. So far, so good.

Changing it to:

```
    if (/\d|\W/.test(charStr)) {
            return false;
        }
```

..will match numbers `\d` or `|` non-word characters `\W`, which is good, except that it's also matching whitespace characters like space and backspace.

So, I'm trying to somehow use `\W`, but with the exception of whitespace characters.

I tried:

```
    if (/\d|\W[^\s]/.test(charStr)) {
            return false;
        }
```

So, match numbers `\d`, or non-word characters `\W` excepting whitespace characters `[^\s]`, but my syntax appears to be wrong here.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: So you don't want it to match whitespace? Can you give us some examples of expected matches, and expected non-matches.

Comment: So you want to *permit* literal backspace characters? (I don't really know what that would even look like, are you sure that's what you want?)

Comment: Honestly no, not sure that's what I want. I was just constructing a solution based on my limited knowledge of regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regexes, whitelisting (telling the engine what you want) is usually much easier than blacklisting (telling what you don't want). If you only want letters and spaces, just say so:

```
/^[a-z ]+$/
```

Note that you have to `trim` the input before using that, otherwise it will "validate" a string consisting entirely of spaces.

Comment: Thanks just hopped in my car, but I'll check this out when I can and mark it correct if it's what I'm looking to do

Comment: Nvm I can tell this is what I want. Thank you! I will keep in mind that white listing is better than blacklisting for regex in the future.